# Cordova build failure

Tags: cordova

I have provided all the path variables in environmental variables. But still I am getting
this error. My adt bundle is placed in 'D' drive. It is refered 'E' Drive.

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\WorkSpace\Insightix\platforms\android\build.xml:90: Cannot find E:\adt-bundle
-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from D:\WorkSpace\Insi
ghtix\platforms\android\build.xml`enter code here`

Total time: 0 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\WorkSpace\Insight
ix\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: D:\WorkSpace\Insightix\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command faile
d with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\go253199\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:enter code here135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your build configuration, android sdk is in  'E:\adt-bundle
-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk' directory. But you placed adt bundle in 'D' drive.

Edit the 'local.properties' file in the 'D:\WorkSpace\Insightix\platforms\android' directory & make sure adt bundle is pointed to the proper location.